# No Debuggable Applications in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, logcat

I am working on this app, with Bluetooth Connectivity, and I ran this app successfully on my phone a couple of times, did a few changes in the MainActivity.java and then ran it on the phone. Android Studio hung up, I force closed it. Then tried running another code through Eclipse IDE where it said it can't access SDK (eventhough it had worked just fine before I downloaded Android Studio). Now I've tried restarting my phone, killing and restarting the ADB, restarting the PC, restarting Android Studio but nothing is working and logcat is not detecting any debuggable apps. When I try to run the app now, it installs in my phone, but the open button is disabled?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.brr.uet.myapplication;

import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.Component;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.HandlesEventDispatching;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.BluetoothClient;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Button;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.CheckBox;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Clock;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.HorizontalArrangement;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Label;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.ListPicker;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.TableArrangement;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.util.YailList;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.events.EventDispatcher;

public class MainActivity extends Form implements HandlesEventDispatching {

    private ListPicker list_dev;
    private Button up, down, left, right, stop, fast, medium, slow, deg0, deg90, deg180;
    private Clock clock;
    private BluetoothClient bt;
    private Label status;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    private HorizontalArrangement hz1, hz2, hz3, hz4;
    private TableArrangement tb;

    void $define() {

        this.ScreenOrientation("portrait");
        this.Title("Bluetooth Control");
        this.BackgroundColor(COLOR_GRAY);
        this.Scrollable(true);

        hz1 = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
        hz1.Visible(true);

        status = new Label(this);
        status.Text("Status: Not Connected");
        status.BackgroundColor(COLOR_RED);
        status.FontBold(true);
        status.FontSize(20);
        status.TextColor(COLOR_WHITE);
        status.FontTypeface(TYPEFACE_DEFAULT);
        status.TextAlignment(Component.ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        status.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        status.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        status.Visible(true);

        list_dev = new ListPicker(hz1);
        list_dev.Text("Connect to Robot");
        list_dev.BackgroundColor(COLOR_BLUE);
        list_dev.Enabled(true);
        list_dev.FontSize(25);
        list_dev.FontTypeface(TYPEFACE_DEFAULT);
        list_dev.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        list_dev.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        list_dev.Visible(true);

        hz2 = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
        hz2.Visible(true);

        checkbox = new CheckBox(hz2);
        checkbox.Text("Enable Camera Rotation");
        checkbox.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        checkbox.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        checkbox.BackgroundColor(COLOR_NONE);
        checkbox.Enabled(false);
        checkbox.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        checkbox.Visible(true);

        hz3 = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
        hz3.Visible(true);

        fast = new Button(hz3);
        fast.Enabled(false);
        fast.Text("Fast");
        fast.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        fast.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        fast.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        fast.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        fast.FontSize(16);
        fast.Visible(true);

        medium = new Button(hz3);
        medium.Enabled(false);
        medium.Text("Medium");
        medium.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        medium.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        medium.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        medium.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        medium.FontSize(16);
        medium.Visible(true);

        slow = new Button(hz3);
        slow.Enabled(false);
        slow.Text("Slow");
        slow.Height(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        slow.Width(Component.LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        slow.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        slow.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        slow.FontSize(16);
        slow.Visible(true);

        tb = new TableArrangement(this);
        tb.Visible(true);

        stop = new Button(tb);
        stop.Enabled(false);
        stop.Image("stop.png");
        stop.Height((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        stop.Width((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        stop.Visible(true);
        tb.$add(stop);

        down = new Button(tb);
        down.Enabled(false);
        down.Image("down.png");
        down.Height((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        down.Width((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        down.Visible(true);

        left = new Button(tb);
        left.Enabled(false);
        left.Image("left.png");
        left.Height((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        left.Width((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        left.Visible(true);

        up = new Button(tb);
        up.Enabled(false);
        up.Height((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        up.Width((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        up.Image("up.png");
        up.Visible(true);

        right = new Button(tb);
        right.Enabled(false);
        right.Image("right.png");
        right.Height((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        right.Width((int) (0.3333 * (LENGTH_FILL_PARENT)));
        right.Visible(true);

        hz4 = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
        hz4.Visible(true);

        deg0 = new Button(hz4);
        deg0.Enabled(false);
        deg0.Text("Rotate 0°");
        deg0.Height(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg0.Width(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg0.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        deg0.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        deg0.FontSize(16);
        deg0.Visible(true);

        deg90 = new Button(hz4);
        deg90.Enabled(false);
        deg90.Text("Rotate 90°");
        deg90.Height(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg90.Width(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg90.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        deg90.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        deg90.FontSize(16);
        deg90.Visible(true);

        deg180 = new Button(hz4);
        deg180.Enabled(false);
        deg180.Text("Rotate 180°");
        deg180.Height(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg180.Width(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        deg180.BackgroundColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
        deg180.TextColor(COLOR_BLACK);
        deg180.FontSize(16);
        deg180.Visible(true);

        bt = new BluetoothClient(this);
        bt.CharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        bt.DelimiterByte(0);

        clock = new Clock(this);
        clock.TimerAlwaysFires(true);
        clock.TimerEnabled(false);
        clock.TimerInterval(1000);

        EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this, "ClickEvent", "Click");
        EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this,"Timer","Timer");
        EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this,"Checkbox","Changed");
        EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this,"List_dev","BeforePicking");
        EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this,"List_dev","AfterPicking");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchEvent(Component component, String compname, String eventname, Object[] args) {

        if (component.equals(up) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("1");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(down) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("2");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(left) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("3");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(right) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("4");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(stop) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("5");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(fast) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("9");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(medium) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("10");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(slow) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("11");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(deg0) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("6");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(deg90) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("7");
            return true;
        }
        else if (component.equals(deg180) && eventname.equals("Click")) {
            bt.Send1ByteNumber("8");
            return true;
        }

        else if (component.equals(list_dev) && eventname.equals("BeforePicking")) {
           // list_dev.BeforePicking();
            list_dev.Elements(YailList.makeList(bt.AddressesAndNames()));
            return true;
        }
        else if(component.equals(list_dev) && eventname.equals("AfterPicking")) {
           // list_dev.AfterPicking();
            bt.Connect(list_dev.Selection());
            if (bt.IsConnected()) {
                up.Enabled(true);
                down.Enabled(true);
                left.Enabled(true);
                right.Enabled(true);
                stop.Enabled(true);
                fast.Enabled(true);
                medium.Enabled(true);
                slow.Enabled(true);
                list_dev.Enabled(false);
                status.BackgroundColor(COLOR_WHITE);
                status.Text("Status: Connected");
                clock.TimerInterval(5000);
                clock.TimerEnabled(true);
                checkbox.Enabled(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                status.BackgroundColor(COLOR_BLACK);
                status.TextColor(Component.COLOR_RED);
                status.Text("Cannot Connect");
                return true;
            }
        }

        else if(component.equals(clock) && eventname.equals("Timer")) {
            if (bt.IsConnected()) {
                clock.TimerInterval(5000);
                clock.TimerEnabled(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                up.Enabled(false);
                down.Enabled(false);
                left.Enabled(false);
                right.Enabled(false);
                stop.Enabled(false);
                fast.Enabled(false);
                medium.Enabled(false);
                slow.Enabled(false);
                list_dev.Enabled(true);
                status.BackgroundColor(COLOR_RED);
                status.Text("Status: Connection Error");
                clock.TimerEnabled(false);
                checkbox.Enabled(false);
                deg0.Enabled(false);
                deg90.Enabled(false);
                deg180.Enabled(false);
                list_dev.Text("Connect to Robot");
                list_dev.BackgroundColor(COLOR_BLUE);
                return true;
            }
        }

        else if(component.equals(checkbox) && eventname.equals("Changed")) {
            up.Enabled(false);
            down.Enabled(false);
            left.Enabled(false);
            right.Enabled(false);
            stop.Enabled(false);
            fast.Enabled(false);
            medium.Enabled(false);
            slow.Enabled(false);
            deg0.Enabled(true);
            deg90.Enabled(true);
            deg180.Enabled(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brr.uet.myapplication">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brr.uet.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Logcat

```
02-27 23:08:09.547 11720-11726/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Success
02-27 23:08:09.716 11720-11726/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Success
02-27 23:08:09.809 1078-1609/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
02-27 23:08:09.830 1078-1609/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
02-27 23:08:22.841 115-340/? E/Cryptfs: not running with encryption, aborting
```